# How to position MUI badge in IconButton border in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have made a Bluetooth connection status indicator using a tooltip and a badge. However I'm struggling with the badge's positioning.

Here's my code:

```
<Tooltip className={classes.help} title={getBluetoothStatus()}>
  <IconButton onClick={props.onClick} size="large">
    <Badge badgeContent="✔" color="success" overlap="circular">
      <BluetoothIcon />
    </Badge>
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: tooltip with badge wrong]

However, I want the badge to be positioned on the edge of the circular IconButton.
I've tried placing the Badge around the IconButton like so:

```
<Tooltip className={classes.help} title={getBluetoothStatus()}>
  <Badge badgeContent="✔" color="primary" overlap="circular">
    <IconButton onClick={props.onClick} size="large">
      <BluetoothIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Badge>
</Tooltip>
```

This does place the Badge more outwards and fixes the issue. Unfortunately it add an unwanted square:

[image]

I've tried adding css properties such as padding, margin and transform:translate to no avail :(

Any thoughts or suggestions are highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to get it looking like intended:

[image]

Had to separate Badge component from the Icon component and then I just styled the badge with `transform: 'translate(30px, -20px)'`

Here's the code I used in case anyone needs it:

```
<Tooltip className={classes.help} title={getBluetoothStatus()}>
  <IconButton onClick={props.onClick} size="large" >
    <Badge badgeContent="✔" color="success" overlap="circular" style={{  transform: 'translate(30px, -20px)'}}>
    </Badge>
    <BluetoothIcon />
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

Let me know if you find a better way.